# How to assign mysql database value to variable in script

Tags: javascript, mysql, dictionary

How to assign database value to a variable in javascript

here mapid is the variable assign the value from the database

```
var geocoder;
  var map;
var mapid
      function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapid);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( {  }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { 
                  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 
                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {

          }
        } else {

        }
      });
    }
  }



<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 270px; height: 267px;">
</div>
```

please share answer here.

Comment: how are you accessing the database?

Comment: @JanR using ajax $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   dataType : 'json',
   url : '/RealEstate/selectminPrice.html',
   data : ({
    id : $('#mapid').val()
   })
  });
 }